# Practical considerations on a mixture of Multivariate Normals, with many terms

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution, finite-mixture-model

Let's say the density of $Y$ is given by $p(y)=\frac{1}{L}\sum^L_{i=1}N(y\mid \mu_i, \Sigma_i)$, where $N(y \mid \mu_i, \Sigma_i)$ is the multivariate normal density evaluated at $y$, with known $L,\mu_i,\Sigma_i$.

1. If I wanted to simulate from $p(y),$ could I just take a multinomial with $L$ probabilities, and then simulate from the respective $i$-th category?
2. If we have a very big $L,$ something like $20,000.$ What's then a good way to sample from that mixture? When generating a sample from a mixture $\sum w_i f_i$, with a given size (N), why not simply take $N_i$ draws from each density $f_i$, such that $\frac{N_i}{N}=w_i$? Can we do it?
3. Is there a closed formula representation for a mixture of multivariate normals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you can take a multinomial with $n=1$ and using a probability vector $p=\mathbb{1}_{1\times L}\frac{1}{L}$. Or use [Categorical Distribution](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Categorical_distribution), which is actually a special case. Another simple method would be generating a [uniform random variable](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) $U$, in $[0,1)$, and choose the category $\lfloor LU \rfloor$ (if numbered from $0$). In non-equal mixture probabilities this is handled internally in random number generation via slight modification of the binary search idea.
2. It shouldn't matter much when you have $L=20000$. But, you can also use the uniform RV approach to get rid of probability vector allocation as well. For your updated extension of Q2, as I've noted in the comments, when split sizes (elements coming from each mixture component) are assumed to be constant, you're not truly sampling the mixture distribution you wrote; even if it can emulate the mixture  in large samples.
3. To the best of my knowledge, there is none. I think, trying to write it in a closer form is like trying to write $e^a+e^b$ in closer form, in which I don't see any further simplification.

Comment: Gunes, thank you for your answer. I still have a question though. When generating a sample from a mixture $\sum w_i f_i$, with a given size (N), why not simply take $N_i$ draws from each density $f_i$, such that $\frac{N_i}{N}=w_i$? Can we do it?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. But you’re then guaranteeing the mixture ratios in every sample. That’s biased.

Comment: why do you say that's biased? In the limit, as sample size tends to infinity, that's what we'll get, right?

Comment: Oh, bad choice of word. It resembles the biased/unbiased estimation. However, yes, in the long run, your samples will better represent the mixture PDF, but note that you're not truly sampling it. Let's say you've $N=100$ and $2$ mixtures. True samples from this mixture would contain the sample split $[40,60]$ or $[45,55]$ for example, but in your way, you'll always get $[50,50]$.

Comment: Gunes, just to be sure, if I number the categories from 1 to n, then I must use the ceiling function instead of the floor, right?

Comment: if numbered from 1, yes ceiling. Tried to note it in the answer :) I was assuming you're going to use 0-based array indexing while accessing your mixture params.